# Given $g(x) = e^{f(2x)}, f(2) = 0, f'(2) = 1$, what is $g'(1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question**.

> Suppose $g(x) = e^{f(2x)}, f(2) = 0, f'(2) = 1.$ Find $g'(1)$.

---

**Current progress and thoughts**.

I've found that  $$\displaystyle g'(x)=e^{f(2x)}\cdot \frac d {dx}f(2x)$$ using the chain rule.
But I do not know how to make use of $f(2)$ or $f'(2)$ to find $g'(1)$.
Is my derivative correct, and I just don't understand how to plug in values? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually is the derivative (e^(f(2x)))*(d/dx(f^2x))?

Comment: Yes but I think I found the derivative

Answer (score 9):

Your derivative seems incorrect, as:

$g(x) = e^{f(2x)}$

$\Rightarrow$ $g'(x) = e^{f(2x)}\cdot {f'(2x)}\cdot 2$ (using chain rule)

Thus, $g'(1) = e^{f(2)}\cdot {f'(2)}\cdot 2=2$ (as $f(2) = 0$, $f'(2) = 1$).

Comment: Why Not make a complete answer? g‘(1)=?

Comment: @miracle173 I have posted a complete answer now. Actually ,I thought hints would better in comments than answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :- Use the first principle of differentiation.
$$f’(x)=\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
**Solution**:- $g(1)=1$,
$g'(1)=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(1+h)-g(1)}{h}
     = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^f(2+2h) -1}{h}$.

Multiply and divide by $f(2+2h)$, and solve the limits after plugging the value
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(2+2h)-0}{2h} =f'(2)=1$$ (I wrote $ f(2+2h)$ from the question as $[f(2+2h)-0]$. $2h$ tends to $0$, so the equation above is derivative of $f$ at $x=2$)
Or you can use L^Hôpital’s rule to solve the last part.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting mathematical expression. It is easy to learn and easy to read on everyone's part.

Comment: Please ise mathjax to format your equations. Use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html (use the mathmode syntax).

Comment: I don’t understand your answer and there is Not Need to Go back to the Definition of th Derivate.